# Can't create new vagrant box from existing created one

Tags: vagrant, box

I have a problem while creating new vagrant box from existing created one. It means I trying to create new box from base box `hashicorp/precise64` and it successfully created e.g. name : `first_box.box`. But, while trying create anothe new box using `first_box.box` as a `base box`, it's not successfully created, it looks like created from `hashicorp/precise64` not from `first_box.box`, for details please see the commands below:

First Step, the VagrantFile is like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "first" do |first|
    first.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
    first.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.31.10"
    first.vm.hostname = "firstserver"
    first.vm.synced_folder "/home/eman/dev", "/home/vagrant/dev"
  end

end
```

and run those commands:

`vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64`

`vagrant up`

`vagrant ssh`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install bla-bla-bla`

`exit`

```
vagrant package --output first_box.box
```

now I have a `first_box.box` inside my vagrant directory.

And then I continue to the second step, creating a new vm by using `first_box.box` as a `base box`, you can see the VagrantFile first:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "second" do |second|
    second.vm.box = "first_box"
    second.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
    second.vm.hostname = "secondserver"
    second.vm.synced_folder "/home/eman/dev", "/home/vagrant/dev"
  end

end
```

and then run those commands again:

`vagrant box add first_box first_box.box`

`vagrant up`

`vagrant ssh`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install another-bla-bla-bla`

`exit`

`vagrant package --output second_box.box`

the problem is, now the `second_box.box` become more little than `first_box.box`. `first_box.box` (650MB), `second_box.box` (647MB). Supposedly it has to be bigger than 650MB because I already install another application in the first and second step.

This is the VagrantFile in the third step:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "third" do |third|
    third.vm.box = "second"
    third.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.35.10"
    third.vm.hostname = "thirdserver"
    third.vm.synced_folder "/home/eman/dev", "/home/vagrant/dev"
  end

end
```

and run those commands:

`vagrant box add second_box second_box.box`

`vagrant up`

`vagrant ssh`

The virtual machine becomes empty, I can't find everything installed from the first and second step.

Anyone know the answer?

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do (I think you should look at provisioning) - also in 3rd file should be `third.vm.box = "second_box"` the size is not a right criteria depending which package you installed. when you start the 2nd box do you correctly see the package installed from 1st box ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri yup, `third.vm.box = "second"` is incorrect, that just an example, not the actual configuration, but represent the actual. btw I just trying to create two version of my development enviroment, the first one is ubuntu 12 + all the dependencies.. the second one is the first env + database + applications

Comment: right so what I would do is a base box on ubuntu and 2 set of provisioning (one incl the dependencies and one incl those dependencies + db)

Comment: the first box I need to create is ubuntu + dependencies with so many installation and configuration (box1), for 2nd box (box2) I don't want to repeat all the installations and configurations, so I just use the the box#1 as a base box, and just do database installation, storing dummy data and install application package. Now, how to create another box which is consist those dependencies, data, and the application from existing vm? because I run the command: `vagrant package --output box2 --base box1` and it didn't work. It just produce an empty box without dependencies, db and application..

Comment: Thats what [provisioning](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/provisioning.html) is for - you can start with a shell script where you'll put all your apt-get package

Comment: This might help https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-create-a-vagrant-base-box-from-an-existing-one#customize-your-new-vagrantfile